# fileManager.copyItem(atPath, toPath) - File exists. But it doesnt

Tags: swift, macos

I encountered this frustrating problem, I hope somebody can help me.
I try to copy item from one folder to another by using fileManager.copyItem(atPath, toPath). Im sure that destination folder is empty but everytime I try to copy I get this error:

**Ooops! Something went wrong: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "“myFileName” couldn’t be copied to “Desktop” because an item with the same name already exists." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/Users/Antan/Desktop/1/myFileName, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Copy
), NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/Antan/Desktop/2, NSFilePath=/Users/Antan/Desktop/1/myFileName, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000045ac40 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=17 "File exists"}}**

Code:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default

do {
    try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: "/Users/Antan/Desktop/1/myFileName", toPath: "/Users/Antan/Desktop/2")

} catch let error as NSError {
     print("Ooops! Something went wrong: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: (lldb) po fileManager.fileExists(atPath: "/Users/Antan/Desktop/2/myFileName")
false
(lldb) po fileManager.fileExists(atPath: "/Users/Antan/Desktop/1/myFileName")
true

Comment: Your source file path and destination path are not even compatible.

Comment: The destination path must include the file name...

Comment: @MartinR ............... amazing... thank you!!